# Add PDF bookmark manually

Tags: pdf, pdftex, bookmarks

I would like to add a bookmark to the table of contents. [This page](http://www.pa.op.dlr.de/~PatrickJoeckel/pdflatex/index.html) shows a method, but `\pdfbookmark` is not recognised as a command. This is my document header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
```

I'm compiling the document with TexMakerX's PDFLaTeX option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a full but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 38):

This works for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{P}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Notice that the `pdftex` options should not be used, as it is supplied automatically when the LaTeX engine used is `pdftex`. Moreover `hyperref` should generally be loaded last, with some exception; one of the exceptions is `bookmark` that eases bookmark management (and is not strictly necessary).

The `\cleardoublepage` is redundant in the example, but is necessary if some copy precedes the table of contents to ensure the correct correspondence of the bookmark with the text.

Answer (score 11):

The `bookmark` package seems to be a powerful and customizable solution, but for most (of my) applications, one usually needs to add the bookmark at or below the current level. For this it is sufficient to use what `hyperref` provides, namely `\belowpdfbookmark{text}{name}` and `\subpdfbookmark{text}{name}`.

As described here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-150004.1

Comment: Loading the package `bookmark` has also the advantage, that the bookmarks are faster uptodate, often one run is sufficient, `hyperref` needs two runs.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, good to know. Do you mean that you need a smaller number of compilation? I think I noticed that. Is this true even if you use the plain `hyperref` commands?

Comment: Yes (and more text to make a comment).

Comment: I found it useful to use **both** `\belowpdfbookmark{text}{contents}` and `\pdfbookmark{other text}{contents}` -- without this, having two `\pdfbookmark`s in my text was causing both of them to be listed on "page 1".