# Make table of contents appear on a PDF index

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, bookmarks

I want the entries for my table of contents at the beginning of my document to appear in the PDF index, for a PDF generated with `pdflatex`.

Currently only my `\chapter` entries appear there, and adding `\chapter` entries for the table of contents is not an option, first of all since it is not an actual chapter and shouldn't be enumerated as such, and also because adding `\chapter` entries adds extra empty pages to my document.

EDIT:
For my bibliography I managed to add it using

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

But can't be sure if there's something similar for the table of contents

Comment: when you say `index`, do you mean the `bookmarks`?

Comment: yeah, well, using several PDF readers, a left bar appears with 'shortcuts' to each chapter I defined on my document. I wish my table of contents and bibliography to appear there too. I can't say if those are the same as the bookmarks of the PDF reader, since a bookmark is something defined by the reader (the person reading the PDF) to easily find certain pages the reader wants to find easily, but they don't depend on the document itself, but on the reader's criteria to define them

Comment: hey! using \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}  works for the bilbiography! :D

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{entry text in the index}
```

does the trick.

Comment: But this adds the table of contents to the table of contents. It's better to use `\currentpdfbookmark{Table of contents}{name}` (from the `hyperref`package) right before `\tableofcontents`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/add-pdf-bookmark-manually .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Timm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/61499/timm) in the comment of an answer here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167069/149079) I eventually found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628508/149079 with a good explanation.

Summary:

**Bookmark on same level**

```
\subpdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{name}        % Bookmark in PDF for TOC
\tableofcontents{}
```

[image: bookmark on same level]

**Bookmark on top level**

```
\pdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{name}        % Bookmark in PDF for TOC
\tableofcontents{}
```

[image]