# Adding bookmarks and subbookmarks manually in regular LaTeX file

Tags: bookmarks

I’m trying to add bookmarks manually. By writing, for instance `\pdfbookmark{I.}{I.}`, it works fine, but I want to add also manually subbookmarks (e.g. in book mark I. add a), b),...). All suggestions are very welcome. With thanks.

Comment: (The documentation can be found at https://texdoc.org/serve/hyperref/0)

Answer (score 4):

`\pdfbookmark` has an optional argument to set the level. Beside this `hyperref` offers a number of commands to switch on level down, see the documentation.

The `bookmark` package offers additional options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{I text}{I}
\pdfbookmark[1]{a) text}{Ia}
\subpdfbookmark{b) text}{Ib}
\currentpdfbookmark{c) text}{Ic}
\belowpdfbookmark{i text}{Ici}
\currentpdfbookmark{d) text}{Id}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]