# Include section in ToC of viewers, but not actually visible in document

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, viewers

I'm writing my thesis, and there are two sections that I do not wish to include in my table of contents: the abstract and the acknowledgements. Of course, LaTeX makes all the right choices for me, so that works out of the box.

However, several PDF viewers render a table of contents outside the document that allows for easy navigation while you're reading it. By default, this seems to be taking the table of contents from the document verbatim, and it works quite nicely. It would seem appropriate to include my abstract and acknowledgements in this list, though, for completeness..

Is there a way to do that? Or is this list really an exact copy of what I'm including in my LaTeX table of contents?

Comment: I think you are looking for bookmarks. The `bookmarks` package might have features to add things directly to the list of bookmarks (I haven't checked)

Comment: At least in `Preview.app`, boomarks and the ToC are two distinct lists, but I cna imagine that this might be overlapping terminology. I'll have a look.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/add-pdf-bookmark-manually might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Joost, the ToC is used to build the list of bookmarks. This is the reason for the `hyperref` warnings about certain chars not being allowed. The bookmark list has to be build in a certain format/charset

Comment: Thanks all. The `bookmarks` package was the solution; I ended up using the `\pdfbookmark` command to achieve this.