# How to add bookmark into dictionary style PDF as output of Tex code

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, dictionaries

I would like to add bookmark into a dictionary style PDF, which is an output of LaTex document. I loaded the package `hyperref` with the optional argument `bookmarks=true`. But I still did not get the bookmark in the PDF output. The dictionary-style Tex code can be looked up in following:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage[top=2.0cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8x,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{marron}{RGB}{60,30,10}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,80}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,80,0}
\definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{0,80,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{80,0,0}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\newcommand{\ornpar}{\noindent \textcolor{darkgray}{ \raisebox{-1.9pt}       [10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt] {\leafright \decofourleft \decothreeleft  \aldineright \decotwo                    \floweroneleft \decoone}}}%

\newcommand{\ornimpar}{\textcolor{darkgray}{\raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\decoone \floweroneright \decotwo \aldineleft \decothreeright  \decofourright \leafleft} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafleft}}}%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\newcommand\entry[4][]{\hangpara{2em}{1}  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{{#2}}}}\ #4\ 
#3 \ifx\relax #1 \relax \markboth{#2}{#2}\else\markboth{#1}{#1}\fi
\vspace*{5pt}\par} \nopagebreak[4]%
\newcommand*{\dictchar}[1]{\centerline{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}\vspace*{10pt}\par}%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%




%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% use fancyhdr or whatever you want to add
% the boxes to the header to make them appear
% on every page

% new counter to hold the current number of the
% letter to determine the vertical position
\newcounter{letternum}
% newcounter for the sum of all letters to get
% the right height of a box
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{26}
% some margin settings
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{2.06cm}%1cm
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{3cm}
% calculate the box height by dividing the page height
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)%
/%
\value{lettersum}
}
% box width
\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{1.5cm}
% style the boxes
\tikzset{
thumb/.style={
fill=black!50!red,
text=white,
minimum height=\thumbheight,
text width=\thumbwidth,
outer sep=0pt,
font=\sffamily\bfseries,
}
}
\newcommand{\oddthumb}[1]{%
% see pgfmanual.pdf for more information about this part
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north east,] at ($%
        (current page.north east)-%
        (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
    $) {#1};                                              
\end{tikzpicture}                                          
}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{%
% see pgfmanual.pdf for more information about this part
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north west,] at ($%
        (current page.north west)-%
        (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
    $) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% create a new command to set a new lettergroup
\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{%

\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{%
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\oddthumb{#1}}% chapters start only on odd pages
\cfoot{\thepage}
}

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[LO]{ \raisebox{1em}{ \fontfamily{phv}     \selectfont{\textbf{\rightmark}} } \oddthumb{#1}}%
\fancyhead[RE]{ \raisebox{1em}{ \fontfamily{phv}   \selectfont{\textbf{\leftmark}} } \eventhumb{#1}}


\fancyhead[LE]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\raisebox{1em}{\rightmark}}}}}


\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\color{darkgray} \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]  {\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{~~~\decofourleft \decotwo \decofourright~~~} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{  \leafleft}}


\fancyhead[RO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\raisebox{1em}{\leftmark}}}}}

 % step the counter of the letters
 \stepcounter{letternum}
 }
 %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%







%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\chaptitle}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}



\fancypagestyle{dictstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead{}

\fancyfoot[LO]{
\ornimpar \\ \hfill \textcolor{darkgray}{\large \leafNE ~~~   \raisebox{-0.35em}{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}} }  }

\fancyfoot[RE]{\ornpar   \\ \textcolor{darkgray}{\large  \raisebox{-0.35em}{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}} ~~~ \reflectbox{\leafNE}}  \hfill  }
}


\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}







%\pagestyle{basicstyle}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
\centering\Huge   \adforn{26}\adforn{21}\quad\adforn{11}\quad\adforn{49}\adforn{54}

\vspace*{2em}\centering\bf  
\texttt{My Dictionary}\par

\vspace{2em}
{\hfill\centering \large{The Author}\hfill} 
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


\pagestyle{dictstyle}%dictstyle
\lettergroup{A}
\dictchar{A}
% \hyperlink{A}{\dictchar{A}} 
\entry[headwords]{headwords}{translations}{\textsf{/yinfu/}}
\entry[headwords2]{headwords2}{translations2}{/yinfu/}
\entry[philosophy]{philosophy} {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, \emph{plac- erat ac}}  {/yinfu/}
\entry[Math]{Math}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{/yinfu/}
\entry[Physics]{Physics}{\lipsum[1-2]}{/yinfu/}
\entry[Nature]{Nature}{\lipsum}{/yinfu/}
\clearpage


\lettergroup{B}
\dictchar{B}
\entry[headwords]{headwords}{translations}{/yinfu/}
\entry[headwords2]{headwords2}{translations2}{/yinfu/}
\clearpage

\lettergroup{C}
\dictchar{C}
\entry[headwords]{headwords}{translations}{/yinfu/}
\entry[headwords2]{headwords2}{translations2}{/yinfu/}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: You should better make a smaller example and show it here instead of asking people to hunt down your code in some other place and then spent a lot time to dissect and shorten it.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer Thanks for your advice. I have updated the post.

Comment: There is no chapter/section/etc... . Related [Add PDF bookmark manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41250/124842)

Comment: You didn't try very much to reduce your code. Beside this: you will have to add them manually as you don't have heading commands. Load the bookmark package and check its documentation.

Comment: @ Bobyandbob That is exactly the confusion  I encounter. There are no sections or chapters in the *dictionary Tex*, and I do not know how to mark a link anchor, which is equivalent to the usage of the command `\section{}`.

Comment: @GL_n Try the `bookmark` package...

Answer (score 1):

I solve the question by myself, and display the adjusted code in following. It may be helpful to some beginner (at least like me). When I posted my question previously I did not know how to set up the link anchor partly. I solved this problem by using the commands `\label{name}` inside the `letter group` and `\pdfbookmark[section]{A or B ...}{name}` before the `letter group`. However, I do not know whether this method is standard or we have other better solutions. The MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage[top=2.0cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8x,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{marron}{RGB}{60,30,10}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,80}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,80,0}
\definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{0,80,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{80,0,0}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\newcommand{\ornpar}{\noindent \textcolor{darkgray}{ \raisebox{-1.9pt}       [10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt] {\leafright \decofourleft \decothreeleft  \aldineright \decotwo                    \floweroneleft \decoone}}}%

\newcommand{\ornimpar}{\textcolor{darkgray}{\raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\decoone \floweroneright \decotwo \aldineleft \decothreeright  \decofourright \leafleft} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafleft}}}%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\newcommand\entry[4][]{\hangpara{2em}{1}  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{{#2}}}}\ #4\ 
#3 \ifx\relax #1 \relax \markboth{#2}{#2}\else\markboth{#1}{#1}\fi
\vspace*{5pt}\par} \nopagebreak[4]%
\newcommand*{\dictchar}[1]{\centerline{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}\vspace*{10pt}\par}%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%




%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% use fancyhdr or whatever you want to add
% the boxes to the header to make them appear
% on every page

% new counter to hold the current number of the
% letter to determine the vertical position
\newcounter{letternum}
% newcounter for the sum of all letters to get
% the right height of a box
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{26}
% some margin settings
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{2.06cm}%1cm
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{3cm}
% calculate the box height by dividing the page height
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)%
/%
\value{lettersum}
}
% box width
\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{1.5cm}
% style the boxes
\tikzset{
thumb/.style={
fill=black!50!red,
text=white,
minimum height=\thumbheight,
text width=\thumbwidth,
outer sep=0pt,
font=\sffamily\bfseries,
}
}
\newcommand{\oddthumb}[1]{%
% see pgfmanual.pdf for more information about this part
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north east,] at ($%
        (current page.north east)-%
        (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
    $) {#1};                                              
\end{tikzpicture}                                          
}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{%
% see pgfmanual.pdf for more information about this part
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north west,] at ($%
        (current page.north west)-%
        (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
    $) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% create a new command to set a new lettergroup
\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{%

\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{%
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\oddthumb{#1}}% chapters start only on odd pages
\cfoot{\thepage}
}

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[LO]{ \raisebox{1em}{ \fontfamily{phv}     \selectfont{\textbf{\rightmark}} } \oddthumb{#1}}%
\fancyhead[RE]{ \raisebox{1em}{ \fontfamily{phv}   \selectfont{\textbf{\leftmark}} } \eventhumb{#1}}


\fancyhead[LE]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\raisebox{1em}{\rightmark}}}}}


\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\color{darkgray} \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]  {\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{~~~\decofourleft \decotwo \decofourright~~~} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{  \leafleft}}


\fancyhead[RO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\raisebox{1em}{\leftmark}}}}}

 % step the counter of the letters
 \stepcounter{letternum}
 }
 %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%







%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\chaptitle}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}



\fancypagestyle{dictstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead{}

\fancyfoot[LO]{
\ornimpar \\ \hfill \textcolor{darkgray}{\large \leafNE ~~~   \raisebox{-0.35em}{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}} }  }

\fancyfoot[RE]{\ornpar   \\ \textcolor{darkgray}{\large  \raisebox{-0.35em}{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}} ~~~ \reflectbox{\leafNE}}  \hfill  }
}


\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}





%\pagestyle{basicstyle}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
\centering\Huge   \adforn{26}\adforn{21}\quad\adforn{11}\quad\adforn{49}\adforn{54}

\vspace*{2em}\centering\bf  
\texttt{My Dictionary}\par

\vspace{2em}
{\hfill\centering \large{The Author}\hfill} 
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\pdfbookmark[section]{A}{sec1}
\pagestyle{dictstyle}%dictstyle
\lettergroup{A}
\dictchar{A}
\label{sec1}
% \hyperlink{A}{\dictchar{A}} 
\entry[headwords]{headwords}{translations}{\textsf{/yinfu/}}
\entry[headwords2]{headwords2}{translations2}{/yinfu/}
\entry[philosophy]{philosophy} {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, \emph{plac- erat ac}}  {/yinfu/}
\entry[Math]{Math}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{/yinfu/}
\entry[Physics]{Physics}{\lipsum[1-2]}{/yinfu/}
\entry[Nature]{Nature}{\lipsum}{/yinfu/}
\clearpage

\pdfbookmark[section]{B}{sec2}
\lettergroup{B}
\dictchar{B}
\label{sec2}
\entry[headwords]{headwords}{translations}{/yinfu/}
\entry[headwords2]{headwords2}{translations2}{/yinfu/}
\clearpage

\pdfbookmark[section]{C}{sec3}    
\lettergroup{C}
\dictchar{C}
\label{sec3}
\entry[headwords]{headwords}{translations}{/yinfu/}
\entry[headwords2]{headwords2}{translations2}{/yinfu/}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

The output of the Tex code above is as follows:

[image]